# Why am I getting errors in lines 56-61?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to set up a problem for state machines in lab and I keep receiving errors when trying to compile in Quartus

I have tried using commas, else statements and nothing seems to work

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.All;

ENTITY SM_VHDL IS  -- Do not modify this entity statement!
  PORT(X       : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
       RESETN,
       CLOCK   : IN  STD_LOGIC;
       Z       : OUT STD_LOGIC;
       Q       : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0)  );
END SM_VHDL;       -- Do not modify this entity statement!


ARCHITECTURE behavior of SM_VHDL IS
  TYPE STATE_TYPE IS (A, B, C);
  SIGNAL state : STATE_TYPE;

BEGIN
    PROCESS(CLOCK, RESETN)
      BEGIN
        IF RESETN = '0' THEN
          state <= A;
        ELSIF CLOCK'EVENT AND CLOCK = '1' THEN
          CASE state IS
            WHEN A =>
              CASE X IS
                WHEN "00"   =>
                                        state <= B;
                                WHEN "11"   =>
                                        state <= C;
                                WHEN OTHERS =>
                                        state <= A;
              END CASE;
            WHEN B =>
              CASE X IS
                WHEN "10"   =>
                                        state <= A;
                                WHEN "11"   =>
                                        state <= C;
                                WHEN OTHERS =>
                                        state <= B;
              END CASE;
            WHEN C =>
              CASE X IS
                WHEN "00"   =>
                                        state <= B;
                                WHEN "01"   =>
                                        state <= A;
                                WHEN OTHERS =>
                                        state <= C;
              END CASE;
          END CASE;
        END IF;
      END PROCESS;

    Z  <= '1' WHEN C;
                  '0' WHEN A;
                  '0' WHEN B;

    Q  <= "00" WHEN A;
                  "01" WHEN B;
                  "10" WHEN C;
                  "11" WHEN "-";

END behavior;
```

I need it to compile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The syntax for assigning to `Z` and `Q` is wrong for multiple issues:

- Missing `WITH state SELECT ...` before assign
- Uses ";" between `when` parts, use `,` instead
- Cant use `"-"` (don't care) after last `when`, use `OTHERS` instead

So updated code:

```
WITH state SELECT Z <=
      '1' WHEN C,
      '0' WHEN A,
      '0' WHEN B;

WITH state SELECT Q <=
      "00" WHEN A,
      "01" WHEN B,
      "10" WHEN C,
      "11" WHEN OTHERS;
```

Btw. consider using ModelSim Starter Edition as compiler/simulator before moving to Quartus, since the compile time is faster and messages often better.

Comment: when has no "others" option, you need to use else, and there are no commas to separate cases in "when", again you use else.

Comment: @Tricky: The original code has syntax errors, so it is hard to say what structure was intended.  My suggestion was to add `WITH state SELECT ...` thereby making the assign a concurrent selected signal assignment, which can have `others` as choices, as per VHDL-2008 std. § 9.3.3.1 (page 480).  The answer you have posted suggest use of concurrent conditional signal assignment, which is also a way to correct the code, and this requires boolean expressions as condition.

Answer (score 0):

WHEN can only be used with boolean conditions. A/B/C are all literals of STATE_TYPE. You need to create a boolean result by creating a comparison on the state signal:

```
Z <=      '1' when STATE = C
     else '0' when STATE = A    -- This state not actually needed as a single ELSE would cover it
     else '0';
```

Ill let you work out the statement for Q

Comment: Please see comment to other answer, as why `when` does not always need a boolean.

Comment: In IEEE Std 1076-2008 there's a condition operator (see 9.2.9) that can be applied implicitly after **when** in a conditional signal assignment statement. The implicit operator is only applied when the condition cannot provide a BOOLEAN result. A form of syntactic sugar. Usage is fairly intuitive applying to conditions and isn't applied to a selected signal assignment choice as shown in Morten's answer which elaborates to a process with a case statement equivalent (10.5.4, 10.9, 14.5.5). A conditional signal assignment elaborates to a process containing an if statement *10.5.3, 10.8, 14.5.5).

Comment: @user1155120 +1 for citing 9.2.9, but I wonder if this is a good idea. Seems to me that implicit conversion on `??` is just a lazy way to bypass strong typing. Surely this just broke the language? It would have made more sense to add a new data type (`logic`??) that can be interpreted as `bit` or `boolean`. IIRC, this was shoe-horned in to allow `bit` in PSL conditionals.

Comment: @EML Invoking an implicit condition operator is semantically clean. The operator is only applied for primary expressions required to be type BOOLEAN (syntactically, conditions) that aren't. For non-predefined types overload resolution is applied to determine the visibility of a function implementing the condition operator. The issue is in having an implicit operator, and moral high ground is long lost, having implicit wait statements, delay models, default values and modes. There are worse outrages.

Comment: @user1155120 Semantically clean, yes, in the sense that the meaning is clear. But consider that `if my_bit` is now valid VHDL, but `my_bit and my_bool` is not, without explicitly overloading `and`. Something is broken, whether or not you're a fan of strong typing (and I'm not). There is no longer a clear definition of what a *type* actually is. The type of an object is meant to describe its interpretation and meaning in any rational language. In VHDL, this sleight of hand means that it no longer does, as type is now determined by context.

Comment: @EML [type: a set of values and a set of operations](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4772740/definitions?ctx=definitions#definitions), my_bit is evaluated using the implicitly applied context operator. The definition of type in VHDL may standout among the 11 definitions in the Standards Dictionary. VHDL as a formal language can be considered rational (reasoned).